# Bootstrap panel not looking the right way

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am playing around with Bootstrap at the moment and trying to understand it all. I am trying to create this image below and make adjustments etc.

[image]

So far I have this but you can see that it does not look right: I tried to make the image bigger as I wanted a bigger size but it screws up everything. Here is my code :

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Mainbody3">
    <div class="pancontrol">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-3">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body"><img src="https://juicerecipes.com/media/cache/7b/c1/7bc189caa0876b4793f6a0ddfd32dae8.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <p>
                  Button
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
              <h4 align="center">
                List Title
              </h4>
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">Item One</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Item Two</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Item Two</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Item Two</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Item Two</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            Here comes some text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
pancontrol{
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);  
    height: 183px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.list-group{
    width: 170px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

When you stretch the window out on jsfiddle you can see the image enlarges but the text just go to the bottom.

Comment: why don't you give the link to the fiddle so that we can play around it too? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d1wu4ojm/12/ Here is the fiddle, like i said i am just trying to see if i built it in the right way and also if i can make the image say like 500 by 500 and keep everything the way it is

Comment: Also i am trying to make the entire pannel like smaller , like the width of the entire pannel 400 px;

Comment: If you change the picture size to 500px by 500px, it would not be possible to keep everything the way it is when you make it smaller. To change the size of the whole panel, you always can use available classes in grid section of bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two main columns have col-lg-10 and col-lg-4, respectively, which overflow the layout because they add up to 14, and the maximum number of available columns is 12. Similarly, col-xs-3 and col-xs-6 only add up to 9, so you can and probably should bump one or both of them up so they equal 12 too.

Before:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

and After:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-6">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-6">
```

I'm not sure exactly how you want your layout to look, so the After code is just one example. Remember, you don't need to explicitly set the width of your columns for every size. If you leave out `col-sm-[num]`, e.g., it will inherit the properties of `col-xs-[num]`

https://jsfiddle.net/dwrx7fpo/

**EDIT:**

Seeing the example site you showed me, I've made a couple adjustments.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-12">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-12">
```

Setting both col-xs classes to col-xs-12 will cause them to stack in mobile or "xs" view. I also removed `width: 800px;` from the .pancontrol selector because it was throwing off the layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/dwrx7fpo/2/

Comment: I actually found a great example on this site: https://juicerecipes.com/recipes/ You can see how the pannel looks, this is what i was trying to go

Comment: Bu ton there site , i am loooking there cols go up to 24 , i am not sure how that makes sense

Comment: See my edit. You can specify the total number of columns on http://getbootstrap.com/ before you download the CSS.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the help , i will try my best and see if i can replicate the same pannel as that website with the same height and width as that is what i was going for x

Comment: No problem. Bootstrap is a great framework to play around with.